# PowerCLI Connect-CIServer -Server

Tags: powershell, powercli

I would like to automate connection to my VMWare CI Server

I have to run this command in PowerCLI to connect:

Connect-CIServer -Server 'serverName' -org 'companyName' -userName 'userName' -pass 'password'

however I was not successful with automating as...

PowerCLI is starting by using:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\Infrastructure\vSphere PowerCLI\vim.psc1" -noe -c ". \"C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\Infrastructure\vSphere PowerCLI\Scripts\Initialize-PowerCLIEnvironment.ps1\""

So I just wonder how I can create powershell or batch file to automate connection to my server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

got it to work by adding ; "Connect-CIServer -Server 'serverName' -org 'companyName' -userName 'userName' -pass 'password'" at the end

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same result in a much neater way. Add this at the top of PS scripts:

```powershell
Add-PSSnapin VMWare.*;
Connect-CIServer -Server 'serverName' -org 'companyName' -userName 'userName' -pass 'password'
```